# landscape/api cannot where to input query commands

Tags: landscape

hi guys cannot seem to input query commands , all i get is "Query API Service" i cannot see where must i input.

example also how to call

Example call:

?action=GetGPGKeys&names.1=mykey

Answer (score 0):

Here is documentation about API you are trying to use:
https://landscape.canonical.com/static/doc/api/gpg.html?highlight=gpg

To start with API please visit https://landscape.canonical.com/static/doc/api/#getting-started-with-the-api
and confirm if you are using:

**command-line client**: easy to use, shell-script friendly

**Python module**: more powerful, recommended if you want to drive the API via Python

**low-level HTTP requests**: in the case you want to know what is going on or write a client for some other language

I personally prefer to use it via CLI (don't forget to source your **LANDSCAPE_API_KEY** and **LANDSCAPE_API_SECRET**, there is a handy file that you can create in your home directory for this)

I just run landscape-api get-gpg-keys on my server and since I do not have any the output was none

> $ landscape-api get-gpg-keys
>
> []

Hope this will help

Thanks

Comment: i did source LANDSCAPE_API_KEY and LANDSCAPE_API_SECRET,  that this mean that i dont have the need for gpg keys to sign my repos ?

Comment: i also prefer the CLI

Comment: Hi @theo Can I please ask you to rewrite your question, and specify what are you trying to accomplish and also step by step with commands that you are using so we can replicate or advise you on the best way forward?

Thanks

Comment: thanks for assisting @bofdan... i manage to get through it. all i wanted was a key to sign my repository. i generated a key to sign my repository.am sorted . thanks